# configure 2 usertypes in django with different profiles and access levels

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've googled for the better part of the night and not getting any solutions that work, so I'm grateful for any new ideas!  I come from more a sysadmin and dba side than programming, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.  I know what I need it to do, just not quite sure how to get there.

My current goal is getting user models and profiles functional before moving on.  I'd like to have 2 user types (vendor, customer).  I've seen this question asked plenty of times, but a real definitive answer to go with, i have not.

I currently have it setup where I have a custom user model and just a baseuser.  I was going to extend from baseser and make a vendor user as well as a customer user but I thought doing just a boolean where it's marked t/f would be easier to steer the users.  I'm open to any ideas.

model.py

```
class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   ...
   is_vendor = models.BooleanField(_('is a vendor account'), default=False)
   ...
```

urls.py  (then I'll create more for the 'Customer' user type.)

```
url(r"^vendors/signup/$", views.vendorsignup, name="vendor_signup"),
url(r"^vendors/login/$", views.vendorlogin, name="vendor_login"),
```

I'd like to have the booleanfield in the model indicate whether the account will be a vendor usertype or not. I'd like to have the field hidden and depending what url they use, it will automatically be marked T/F and hidden. I have no idea where to put this logic (view? form? etc) and can't find what code it would actually be.  When the boolean is marked true (as it always would be from a vendor signup page, the vendor would be assigned the Vendor auth group and i can give permissions thru there and also point them to the correct profile/options.

Any help much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue, and from a dba stand point as well, i decided not to change django's base user model and created a user profile with a OneToOne relation. All "custom" properties for each type, site specific etc goes in the profile.